# I am trying to install CIVICRM on Drupal 9.4.1 using composer as per instruction found here https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal/

Tags: installation

When i enter "composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}:'~5.61'"
getting error like " Could not parse version constraint '~5.61': Invalid version string "'~5.61'""

how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you on windows? You'll need to use `"` instead of `'`.

Comment: yes i am using windows 10